# Is it possible to start multiple services from one Console Application by Topshelf?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, topshelf

As TosShelf says:

`"You can only have ONE service! As of 3.x Topshelf the base product no longer support hosting multiple services.` "

as of version 3.x I need to figure out how to integrate the new version of Topshelf.

**Question:**
Is it possible to start multiple separate services from one Console Application using Topshelf? How can I achieve that?

Comment: I think theres a nuget package you can add to handle multiple services but i cant remember the name off the top of my head, topshelf.something i think

Comment: Would be great if you could :)

Comment: "This feature will most likely come back in the form of an add on nuget." perhaps they haven't done it yet? i couldn't see one in nuget sorry

Comment: maybe if you really want it just grab a pre-3.0 ver of the library `Install-package topshelf -version 2.3`

Answer (score 12):

Topshelf no longer supports this but a possible work around would be to implement a class to start multiple services.

Example:

```
// ServiceManager is used to start and stop multiple services
hostConfigurator.Service<ServiceManager>(s => 
{
        s.ConstructUsingNinject(); // service1 and service2 injected into ServiceManager
        s.WhenStarted(tc => tc.Start());
        s.WhenStopped(tc => tc.Stop());
});
```

The ServiceManager class then would just start and stop multiple services.

```
public class ServiceManager
{
    private readonly Service1 service1;
    private readonly Service2 service2;

    public ServiceManager(Service1 service1, Service2 service2)
    {
        this.service1= service1;
        this.service2= service2;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        service1.Start();
        service2.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        service1.Stop();
        service2.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jason! Could you please post a code how to use ConstructUsingNinject? or better with Autofac (if you are familiar with it). Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

As of now there is not a method to host multiple services in a single windows service nor are there plans to implement this functionality. Monitoring and managing these services isn't possible with existing tools which is one of the primary drivers for this decision.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question, but might help.

According to [this guide](https://akshay-zz.medium.com/how-to-create-windows-service-to-schedule-task-with-topshelf-and-fluentscheduler-part-2-f470a57a4532) you can create multiple schedules using [FluentScheduler](https://fluentscheduler.github.io/) and use those to run multiple services from one Topshelf app.